# Nodejs with mongodb API performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, concurrency

I have created nodejs API for one of my application. It reads data from mongodb.
Single API call takes ~2.75ms.

[image]

But when I make 6 concurrent API calls response time increases drastically for each call up to
~12ms.

[image]

I am using chrome browser.

I am not able to figure out what could be the bottleneck. Any suggestion which part to
debug is most welcome.

Comment: What happens at concurrency 2, 3, 4 and 5?

Comment: Could you provide more description or code of your 2nd,3rd,4th queries? My first clue, this aren't simple `find` and I am 99% sure it's a performance issue relative with indexes.

Comment: Also, it might be useful, even if all queries have the same code, (or it's the same API endpoint) it could be problem with RAM on server-side machine, if Mongo doesn't have enough RAM, it will response data for some queries with a delay.

Comment: Where is your DB hosted ? "MongoDB Compass" has a Performance Monitor, connect it with your DB and see what happens on requests